# Is it possible to filter the answers with the expected criteria?

Tags: discussion, search

Is it possible to filter the `answers` with the below criteria?

- It should be answer only - `is:answer`
- Answer score to be zero - `score:0`
- Recent answer - selected the `newest` tab
- Not an accepted answer
- User reputation is less than 100

I can achieve the first 3 criteria by this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer%20score%3a0

How can i add the `not an accepted answer` also in the search criteria, is it possible?. `hasaccepted:no` is not working with this.

I think filter by user reputation is not possible, is there any way to filter the `answer` by reputation?

Comment: `hasaccepted:no` is a _question_ filter, not one for answers. Instead, you want `isaccepted:no` to filter _answers_ that aren't accepted. As for reputation, no, there is currently not way to filter by rep.

Comment: You have enough rep to access the review queue. If you really want to look at answers from new users you can go to the First Posts and Late Answers queues.